# Interfacing a CCTV camera (AV output) with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno

I have to use a camera to take picture in my major project. I want to use [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42CDx.jpg) camera, which has AV output. Please tell me how to interface this camera with my Arduino Uno and use the data from camera and send it to my PC using a Wi-fi Module?

P.S. Please do not suggest me to use wireless camera because firstly they are expensive and secondly I require a board in my project anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I have to tell you that a UNO isn't enough powerful to work with any type of camera: it hasn't got enough ram and processing power to elaborate your camera's data. ([see atmega328P's specs](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega328.aspx))

I'm not sure you can work with that camera, unless it is digital and has integrated RAM to keep the frames.

A good project which I suggest you to see is [arducam](http://www.arducam.com/).

Comment: Can you suggest me any camera to work with UNO?

Comment: In the answer I linked you [arducam](http://www.arducam.com/)

Comment: yeah, I saw that but arducam are not low cost and are not widely available in India. Can you check [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/ttl-serial-camera/overview) blog and tell me the possibilities of it's happening. Thank you

Comment: Can you give a link to the camera you want ot use? I need more of a photo.

Also, I have read the guide on Adafruit that you have linked, and it might work but from what I have read to take a photo it takes over two thousand milliseconds, so it isn't very fast

Comment: [Camera](http://www.ebay.in/itm/CCTV-CAMERA-CMOS-600-TVL-212-/291405572779?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_203&hash=item43d9202aab) I want to use.

Comment: Unfortunately that's analogic, I don't know how to use it.